# Community Landing Page Controller

Tags: apex, community, controller, lightning-community, customer-community-plus

I have a Community with 3 home pages created using community builder. My requirement is that depending on a field on the User record, the user who has logged in should be redirected to different home pages.

I am trying to use an apex class to achieve this, as given in the Salesforce documentation

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_configure_custom_home_page_with_oauth.htm&type=5

Code below

```
 public class CommunitiesLandingController {

// Code we will invoke on page load.
public PageReference forwardToStartPage() {
    System.debug('************');
    String communityUrl = 'https://google.com'; //URL of new page
 return new PageReference(communityUrl);
}

public CommunitiesLandingController() {
}
```

}

My problem here is that forwardToStartPage method is not being called at all. Even the debug is not printing.

I am logging in to the Community using the Manage External User -> Log in to Community as user button on External User's Contact Record.

Comment: Have you considered using [Audience Targeting](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=community_builder_page_visibilty_overview.htm&type=5) instead?

Comment: @DavidCheng, audience targeting will not work. I have simplified the requirement here. It's is much more complex. And the complex logic cannot be implemented using audience targeting.